# JavaScript: Create a function groupBy that accepts an array and a callback, and returns an object

Tags: javascript, function, object, if-statement, keyvaluepair

My Objective is the following:

Create a function groupBy that accepts an array and a callback, and returns an object. groupBy will iterate through the array and perform the callback on each element. Each return value from the callback will be saved as a key on the object. The value associated with each key will be an array consisting of all the elements that resulted in that return value when passed into the callback.

The code below successfully executes:

```
function groupBy(array, inputFunc) {
    let obj = {};

  for(let i of array){
    let key = inputFunc(i);

    // QUESTION on line of code below: 
    console.log(obj[key])

    if(obj[key] === undefined){
      obj[key] = [];
    }
        obj[key].push(i)
  }
  return obj; 
}

// Uncomment these to check your work!
const decimals = [1.3, 2.1, 2.4];
const floored = function(num) { return Math.floor(num); };


console.log(groupBy(decimals, floored)); // should log: { 1: [1.3], 2: [2.1, 2.4] }
```

But I'm a bit confused by the code.  Specifically, when I do:

```
console.log(obj[key])
```

the above line of code appears to return:

```
undefined
undefined
[ 2.1 ]
undefined
```

Why is it printing undefined?  Where is that coming from?

Because I do not understand where the undefined is coming from, I don't comprehend why the if statement is needed.

Comment: because of the array sort, when the function executes, it searches if there is "1" in the obj and there is not so it prints `undefined` then it searches for "2" which is `undefined` then after adding it to `obj` it prints 2.1 because there is value in "2" (`key`) which is [2.1] because the function pushed to the "2" (`key`) 2.1 (array) then it becomes [2.1] and the last `undefined` should not be printed but I assume it's from browser console

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
console.log(obj[key])
```

you do not know if the object has said key or not; after all, it's only *after* that that you assign an array to that key, if there's no associated value:

```
if(obj[key] === undefined){
  obj[key] = [];
}
```

So, on each iteration, if the key being iterated over has not been put onto the object yet, it will log `undefined`, and later in the same iteration, an empty array will be assigned to that key on the object.

For example, on the first iteration, `i` is `1.3`, so the generated key is `let key = inputFunc(i);` -> `let key = inputFunc(1.3);` -> `let key = 1`. But the object starts out with no keys at all, so

```
obj[1]
```

evaluates to `undefined`, the later `if` statement detects this, and assigns an array to that key:

```
if(obj[key] === undefined){
  obj[key] = [];
}
```

on the first iteration, resolves to

```
if(obj[1] === undefined){
  obj[1] = [];
}
// ->
if(undefined === undefined){
  obj[1] = [];
}
```

You could also consider using `reduce` instead, which is more functional and arguably more appropriate when transforming an array into a singular value:

```js
const groupBy = (array, inputFunc) => array.reduce((a, elm) => {
  const key = inputFunc(elm);
  if (!a[key]) {
    a[key] = [];
  }
  a[key].push(elm);
  return a;
}, {});

const decimals = [1.3, 2.1, 2.4];
const floored = function(num) { return Math.floor(num); };


console.log(groupBy(decimals, floored)); // should log: { 1: [1.3], 2: [2.1, 2.4] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it's showing whether the item exists or not. If it doesn't, it goes to the `if` statement. Put the `console.log` after the `if` statement to remove all `undefined`.

```js
function groupBy(array, inputFunc) {
  let obj = {};
  for (let i of array) {
    let key = inputFunc(i);
    if (obj[key] === undefined) {
      obj[key] = [];
    }
    console.log(obj[key]);
    obj[key].push(i);
  }
  return obj;
}

const decimals = [1.3, 2.1, 2.4];
const floored = function(num) {
  return Math.floor(num);
};

console.log(groupBy(decimals, floored));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Note that it's not needed - if all you want is the `obj` returned from the function:

```js
function groupBy(array, inputFunc) {
  let obj = {};
  for (let i of array) {
    let key = inputFunc(i);
    if (obj[key] === undefined) {
      obj[key] = [];
    }
    obj[key].push(i);
  }
  return obj;
}

const decimals = [1.3, 2.1, 2.4];
const floored = function(num) {
  return Math.floor(num);
};

console.log(groupBy(decimals, floored));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function groupBy(arr, CB) {
  let fOut = {};
  
  arr.forEach( (e) => {
    if (!fOut[CB(e)]) fOut[CB(e)] = []; // if theres no key for the CB(e), create and set value as empty arr
    fOut[CB(e)].push(e);    // push the (raw) element to the key of CB(e)
  });
  
  return fOut;
}
```